# Component 'RCTView' re-registered direct event 'topClick' as a bubbling event

Tags: javascript, react-native

`react native 0.73.1

node 20.10.0

NMapsMap 3.17.0

I installed nmap using npm i https://github.com/zerocho/react-native-naver-map

It runs normally on Android devices, but builds on ios simulator, but the following error occurs

'

```
Component 'RCTView' re-registered direct event 'topClick' as a bubbling event

RCTModuleConstantsForDestructuredComponent
RCTUIManager.m:1533
moduleConstantsForComponentData
\__28-\[RCTUIManager getConstants\]\_block_invoke
__NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
\-\[\__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:\]
\-\[RCTUIManager getConstants\]
\-\[RCTUIManager constantsToExport\]
\-\[RCTModuleData gatherConstantsAndSignalJSRequireEnding:\]
\-\[RCTModuleData exportedConstants\]
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::getConstants()
facebook::react::ModuleRegistry::getConfig(std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \> const&)
facebook::react::JSINativeModules::createModule(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \> const&)
facebook::react::JSINativeModules::getModule(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&)
facebook::react::JSIExecutor::NativeModuleProxy::get(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&)
facebook::jsi::DecoratedHostObject::get(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&)
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::JsiProxy::get(hermes::vm::SymbolID)
hermes::vm::JSObject::getComputedWithReceiver_RJS(hermes::vm::Handle\<hermes::vm::JSObject\>, hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::Handle\<hermes::vm::HermesValue\>, hermes::vm::Handle\<hermes::vm::HermesValue\>)
hermes::vm::CallResult\<hermes::vm::HermesValue, (hermes::vm::detail::CallResultSpecialize)2\> hermes::vm::Interpreter::interpretFunction\<false, false\>(hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::InterpreterState&)
hermes::vm::Runtime::interpretFunctionImpl(hermes::vm::CodeBlock\*)
hermes::vm::Runtime::runBytecode(std::\__1::shared_ptr\<hermes::hbc::BCProviderBase\>&&, hermes::vm::RuntimeModuleFlags, llvh::StringRef, hermes::vm::Handle\<hermes::vm::Environment\>, hermes::vm::Handle\<hermes::vm::HermesValue\>)
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::evaluatePreparedJavaScript(std::\__1::shared_ptr\<facebook::jsi::PreparedJavaScript const\> const&)
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntime::evaluateJavaScriptWithSourceMap(std::\__1::shared_ptr\<facebook::jsi::Buffer const\> const&, std::\__1::shared_ptr\<facebook::jsi::Buffer const\> const&, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \> const&)
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::evaluateJavaScript(std::\__1::shared_ptr\<facebook::jsi::Buffer const\> const&, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \> const&)
facebook::jsi::RuntimeDecorator\<facebook::jsi::Runtime, facebook::jsi::Runtime\>::evaluateJavaScript(std::\__1::shared_ptr\<facebook::jsi::Buffer const\> const&, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \> const&)
facebook::jsi::WithRuntimeDecorator\<facebook::react::(anonymous namespace)::ReentrancyCheck, facebook::jsi::Runtime, facebook::jsi::Runtime\>::evaluateJavaScript(std::\__1::shared_ptr\<facebook::jsi::Buffer const\> const&, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \> const&)
facebook::react::JSIExecutor::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)
facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)
decltype(std::declval\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1&\>()(std::declval\<facebook::react::JSExecutor\*\>())) std::\__1::\__invoke\[abi:v160006\]\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1&, facebook::react::JSExecutor\*\>(facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1&, facebook::react::JSExecutor\*&&)
void std::\__1::\__invoke_void_return_wrapper\<void, true\>::\__call\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1&, facebook::react::JSExecutor\*\>(facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1&, facebook::react::JSExecutor\*&&)
std::\__1::\__function::\__alloc_func\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1, std::\__1::allocator\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1\>, void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>::operator()\[abi:v160006\](facebook::react::JSExecutor\*&&)
std::\__1::\__function::\__func\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1, std::\__1::allocator\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry\> \>, std::\__1::unique_ptr\<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::\__1::default_delete\<facebook::react::JSBigString const\> \>, std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\> \>)::$\_1\>, void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor\*&&)
std::\__1::\__function::\__value_func\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>::operator()\[abi:v160006\](facebook::react::JSExecutor\*&&) const
std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor\*) const
facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8::operator()() const
decltype(std::declval\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8&\>()()) std::\__1::\__invoke\[abi:v160006\]\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8&\>(facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8&)
void std::\__1::\__invoke_void_return_wrapper\<void, true\>::\__call\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8&\>(facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8&)
std::\__1::\__function::\__alloc_func\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8, std::\__1::allocator\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8\>, void ()\>::operator()[abi:v160006]()
std::\__1::\__function::\__func\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8, std::\__1::allocator\<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::\__1::function\<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor\*)\>)::$\_8\>, void ()\>::operator()()
std::\__1::\__function::\__value_func\<void ()\>::operator()[abi:v160006]() const
std::\__1::function\<void ()\>::operator()() const
facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::\__1::function\<void ()\> const&)
facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::\__1::function\<void ()\> const&)
facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1::operator()() const
decltype(std::declval\<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1&\>()()) std::\__1::\__invoke\[abi:v160006\]\<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1&\>(facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1&)
void std::\__1::\__invoke_void_return_wrapper\<void, true\>::\__call\<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1&\>(facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1&)
std::\__1::\__function::\__alloc_func\<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1, std::\__1::allocator\<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1\>, void ()\>::operator()[abi:v160006]()
std::\__1::\__function::\__func\<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1, std::\__1::allocator\<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>&&)::$\_1\>, void ()\>::operator()()
std::\__1::\__function::\__value_func\<void ()\>::operator()[abi:v160006]() const
std::\__1::function\<void ()\>::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::\__1::function\<void ()\>)
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
\__CFRunLoopDoBlocks
\__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
\+\[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop\]
__NSThread__start__
\_pthread_start
thread_start
```

'
clean build folder
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package-lock.json
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
npm install
pod install

It all didn't work`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue and pushed to github repo. Please reinstall the package, thank you!
해당 이슈 수정해서 github에 올려두었습니다. 다시 최신으로 설치해보세요~